# Mysql Search and Replace query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, if-statement, sql-update

I'm trying to search a column for a specific result.  If found change the value of another column in the same table with a specific number.

**Example** Using table `product` while searching column `manufacturer_id` for number `5`.  If found change the value of `status` to `0` on the same row.

I have been able to modify examples on the net but I have only been successful in changing all rows to 0 or just locating the "5" in manufacturer_id and errors on the update side. I have tried to do it with if then statements with no luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty basic update statement.  What have you tried that isn't working?

```
Update product 
set status = 0 
where manufacturer_ID = 5
```

Databases operate best on set logic.  So we identified all records in product with a manufacturer_Id of 5 and set their status to 0.

A different approach would be to do this on a line by line basis but it is FAR less efficient as it must evaluate every record in the table.  Whereas the first option is able to quickly limit the records to modify to those with manufacturer_ID of 5.

update product 
set status = case when manufacturer_Id = 5 then 0 else status end

Comment: I have never done any sql queries before so just learning on the fly. It seems where I was erroring was trying to turn it in to a two step process in finding the desired result then trying to modify the other column.

Comment: When using SQL think in terms of sets of data.  line by line approach is far less efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful response. Seems I need to do a bit more learning on sql queries. Any suggestions where to start? I will accept the answer when the timer is up.

Comment: some nice intro SQL tutorials can be found on http://sqlzoo.net/  Get the basics down first and then bulid on them.